# Path of file in Ubuntu for JS

Tags: apache2, video

This maybe possible duplicate, but didn't found exact problem as me.

I have a Ubuntu server, which running Flask over Apache, problem is I have next path:

```
 /var/www/someapp/video.mp4. And app.py file inside 
 /var/www/someapp/app.py and inside of this file I need to access
```

to this `video.mp4` file. I trying to access it by:

```
'/var/www/someapp/video.mp4' or '/video.mp4' or './video.mp4'
```

but nothing works. The browser shows

> 404 or NS_BINDING_ABORTED.

I guess there is problem with access to this files, but not sure exactly.
Any suggestions why this isn't working and how can I fix it?

Comment: About JS, I mean access video file inside of JS <source src="">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask automatically serves files from Static thus you should move your video to a static subdirectory:

`/var/www/someapp/static/video.mp4`

Then in ypur flask refer the file using url_for but first import url_for

```
from flask import url_for

video_url = url_for('static', filename='video.mp4')
```

Use video_url to reference your file:

```
<video src="{{ video_url }}" controls>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Then configure Apache and add `Alias` to direct to the URL path for the folder holding the video:

```
Alias /videos /var/www/someapp/static
<Directory /var/www/someapp/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart Apache:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Ensure file permissions for teh video and parent directory allow reading of the file. You can do this using:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/someapp/static
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/someapp/static
```